# React router doesn't show anything on the new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement a simple program that contains the router in react. I am using 'react-router-dom' for it.

Here's how my App.jsx looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Headerbar } from './HeaderBar.jsx';
import Home from './Home.jsx';
import About from './About.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Headerbar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route
              path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

This is being called from the index.js which reads something like this

```
import './styles/global.scss';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now the components that I am trying to render are very simple one'. One of them 'About.jsx' reads something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('about component');
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <h1>About page</h1>
                <a href="/">Go back to home</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

something similar is the code for the Home component.

Following here is the HeaderBar.jsx which contains the link that changes the route.

```
import '../styles/components/headerBar.scss';
import React from 'react';

export class Headerbar extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="header-container">
                <div className="heading">
                    <h1 className="header-text">Simple User List</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="links">
                    <a href="/about" style={{float:"right"}}>About</a>
                    <a href="/" style={{float:"right"}}>Home</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help in this respect is much appreciated. Also if you could point out the best practise that could be followed while creating such code blocks. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have bad path on this line.

```
<Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
```

Just change to

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 0):

No route matches your root path
either you can change one of your path to `"/"` or you can redirect to one of your route, just add this inside switch statement in App.jsx

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/home" />)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the initial thing,

instead of Route `path='/home'` you should have `path='/'`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Headerbar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route
              path="/" exact component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

or use `Redirect`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Headerbar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route
              path="/home" exact component={Home} />
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

and

Secondly instead of using `anchor tag`, use `Link` to change the route

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class About extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('about component');
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <h1>About page</h1>
                <Link to="/">Go back to home</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
export class Headerbar extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="header-container">
                <div className="heading">
                    <h1 className="header-text">Simple User List</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="links">
                    <Link to="/about" style={{float:"right"}}>About</Link>
                    <Link to="/" style={{float:"right"}}>Home</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: which is the second route, what do you mean it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Please update the about component route as follows in your App component 
`<Route exact path="/" component={About} />`
Instead of
`<Route  path="/about" exact component={About} />`

Since browser by default points to '/' initially.

Comment: even after making this change it isn't redirecting to the second path.